# How do I upgrade from Ubuntu Server 12.10 to Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, ubuntu-server

Hi I would like to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 12.10 which I have no idea how to use, to Ubuntu Desktop so that I can install my Windows Server 2008.
Please help.
Thank

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I got the message "unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix missing?"

Comment: did you read that it says `run apt-get update or try with --fix`. it means execute sudo apt-get update before executing sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop. If you still get the same error then try it apt-get --fix install. I assume you have internet connection when you execute these command

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You need to run [apt-get update](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) once before installing new packages as this updates the local repository information. `apt-get upgrade` will fetch new versions of packages existing on the machine if Apt knows about these new versions by way of `apt-get update`.

Now you will be able to run the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I have tried this but when I look back over I see there is "err" or "Failed to fetch" before a weblink. I am connected to the internet on it as far as I know.

Comment: so after I log on I should type: echo nameserver 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Ok, I have the Google DNS installed, but when I tested it (nslookup google.com) it did not respond

Comment: @user176520: the output the command `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: i ran that command and it is all there. 
"nameserver 8.8.8.8"
"nameserver 8.8.4.4"

Comment: I have ubuntu desktop on a burnt onto a usb using iso to usb. Is there a way I can run it onto the ubuntu server?>

Comment: @user176520: It also is possible. Restart your computer, enter the bios and set to boot from the USB stick.